# Why my function returns an unexpected result?

Tags: php, function

Here is my function:

```
function getShortNum($n) {
    if     ( $n < 10000 )     return $n;
    elseif ( $n < 100000 )    return round( $n / 1000, 1) . "k";
    elseif ( $n < 1000000 )   return floor( $n / 1000 )   . "k";
    elseif ( $n < 1000000000) return floor( $n / 1000000) . "M";
    else                      return "Wow!!!";      
}
```

As you see, my function converts long numbers to short numbers. Here is some examples:

```
1        => 1
10       => 10
100      => 100
1000     => 1000
1001     => 1001
10000    => 10k
10100    => 10.1k
100000   => 100k
101000   => 101k
101111   => 101k
1000000  => 1M
1111111  => 1M
10111111 => 10M
11000000 => 11M
```

Ok, all fine. Just when I pass a letter to that function, it returns exactly the same thing. For example:

```
echo getShortNum("N"); // output: N
```

Why? All my conditions are about numbers in that function, not letters. So how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because PHP does [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). It will convert the string "N" to an integer so it can do the comparisons you have in your if/else statements. "N" becomes zero which matches your first comparison.

Type juggling is a very important aspect of PHP as not fully understanding it can result in hard to detect bugs and unexpected results.

If your goal is to prevent non-numeric values from being converted you should check the data type using functions such as [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php), [`is_integer()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-integer.php), and [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manuala/en/function.filter-var.php).

Answer (score 3):

When you convert `N` to a number to compare `$n < 10000`, `$n` becomes `0`, which results in the first conditional being true. (Which is to just return `$n`, which is in this case, is `N`.)